# Unable to filter after Date in Realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to apply a filter on realm which includes a Date but with no luck.

I've found out that Date object cannot be passed because the %@ format expects a Foundation object as argument, so I've applied a cast to NSDate.

```
let newDate = Date()
realm.objects(E.self)
            .filter(String(format: "%@ <= %@", key, newDate as NSDate)).first
```

The issue that appears is "Unable to parse the format string timestamp==2020-03-20 08:21:00 +0000"

`key` is the name of the field, which in this case it is "timestamp" and on the model it has the type Date.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant to write `.filter("\(key) <= %@", newDate as NSDate)`?

Comment: I've successfully used `.filter(String(format: "%@ = '%@'", key, value)).first` before, but it was with a string, not a Date. I'm not 100% sure how it should be done, but I'll try with your suggestion as well, thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper it seems to work, but I'm not sure why :)) Could you please post an answer with this and maybe an explanation so I can mark it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
.filter("\(key) <= %@", newDate as NSDate)
```

This is calling the overload of Realm's `filter` method that accepts a format and arguments.

`String(format:)` is not the right thing to use here, as that just does general string formatting. But here, you want the date to be formatted according to the rules of `NSPredicate` formats. On the other hand, the `key` can just be interpolated into the string because the name of the table column doesn't need a special format.

If `key` comes from a `UITextField` or something like that, then you might need to beware of injection attacks as well, and validate and/or escape the `key` properly beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much, the key comes from a service within react-native, so I don't think that would be a problem.